# Breadth First Search(BFS) and Depth First Search(DFS)

Tags: algorithm, search, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

Came across this piece of information on an online course for algorithms: 
BFS is used to find connected components for a undirected graph whereas DFS is used to find connected components for a directed graph.
Can i do the opposite here and if I do what would be the drawbacks on performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the main difference between DFS and BFS. Both of them can be applied on either directed graph or undirected graph. Usually DFS consumes much lower memory than BFS, because BFS has to store all child pointers at each level of the search tree. But DFS can store the queue (only one path) in the stack.

Usually DFS is faster than BFS, has less complexity of space, and is easy to be implemented. But in some problems (like finding shortest path), DFS is not as useful or efficient as BFS.

From the aspect of the search tree, BFS and DFS are actually the same algorithm but with different data structure.